# Feature wise center in ImageDataGenerator

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

The feature wise center means we have to subtract the mean value of dataset from the image. So in ImageDataGenrator if I set featurewise_center=True it will do same. I have 2 questions.

1. That mean values calculated over augmented data or the data which is stored in train directory?
2. At test time I want that same values of mean to subtract from test image. How to get that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**That mean values calculated over augmented data or the data which is stored in train directory?**

According to the [Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator):

> fit(x, augment=False, rounds=1, seed=None )
>
> Fits the data generator to some sample data.
>
> This computes the internal data stats related to the data-dependent
> transformations, based on an array of sample data.
>
> Only required if featurewise_center or featurewise_std_normalization
> or zca_whitening are set to True.
>
> When rescale is set to a value, rescaling is applied to sample data
> before computing the internal data stats.

So, you shall fit the ImageDataGenerator to some image data previously stored as an array of rank 4 and choose if you want to compute the stats based on the augmented images or not, by setting the 'augment' parameter to True or False. If you don't fit the data to the ImageDataGenerator object, it will just ignore the featurewise center transformation.

**At test time I want that same values of mean to subtract from test image. How to get that one?**

You can copy the stats from one Data Generator to another and you won't have to fit the Data Generator for the test set. After you fit the train Data Generator, just copy the stats to the test Data Generator, E.g

```
image_train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
                                                   featurewise_center=True,
                                                   horizontal_flip = True, 
                                                   rotation_range = 20, 
                                                   zoom_range = 0.2, 
                                                   shear_range = 0.1, 
                                                   )

image_train_datagen.fit(fit_array)

image_test_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=True)

image_test_datagen.mean = image_train_datagen.mean
```

You may copy the std. deviation(for featurewise std normalization, by copying the 'std' attribute) and principal components (for zca whitening, by copying the 'principal_components' attribute) as well.